# Example of an irreducible algebraic set consisting of more than one polynomial

Tags: algebraic-geometry

By definition, an algebraic set is a zero locus of polynomials:

$$ \{x\in \mathbb A^n \mid p(x) = 0 \,\,\,\, \forall p \in S\}$$

where $S$ is a set of polynomials $p \in k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$.

It is called irreducible if it cannot be written as a union of two proper algebraic subsets.

It seems to me that whenever $|S|>1$ the set is irreducible. So the only algebraic varieties are ones that are the zero locus of just one single polynomial.

Am I missing something?

> Are there irreducible algebraic sets with $|S|>1$?

Comment: irreducible over what?

Comment: When $\#(S)>1$, you get an *intersection* of two (or more) algebraic sets, so what does this have to do with irreducibility?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I made a mistake and thought of it as the union of the loci rather than the intersection. Sometimes these mistakes just happen to me even though I know better. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Try the zero set of $X$ and $Y$ in $\mathbb A^2$.

Comment: Do you mean $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb A^2 \mid p(x,y) = x = 0\} \cap \{(x,y)\in \mathbb A^2 \mid p(x,y) = y = 0\} $? If so wouldn't this set just be the origin $(0,0)$? And wouldn't this equal $\{(x,y) \mid p(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 = 0\} = \{(0,0)\}$ so it would indeed have $|S|=1$? What am  I missing?

Comment: @student If the base field is $\mathbb C$, then $x^2+y^2=0$ also has solutions $(i, 1)$ (and more).

Comment: @hwong557 I am assuming the base field is $\mathbb R$. I need to understand the easy case first. Then move on to the complex case and so on.

Comment: @student The complex case works out far nicer and actually easier than in the real case. But I guess it depends on what your goal is.

Comment: Frankly speaking, it makes no sense to think of the real case in this problem, as zero set of any set of polynomials can be given by one single polynomial, i.e., $f_1 ^2 + f_2 ^2 + \ldots + f_k^2= 0$.So there is nothing revealing about zero set of a single polynomial in the real case.